# Error Storing static function from another class in BiFunction

Tags: java, functional-programming

I have two classes and, in one of them, I want to create a variable that will hold a function from the other class. I want to do this so I can change behaviour dinamically conditionally.

I tried the following prototype which results in a compilation error:

```
class A {
    public String myFn(int a, int b) {
        return "<" + a + " " + b + ">";
    }
    public String myFn2(int a, int b) {
        return "(" + a + " " + b + ")";
    }
}

class B {
    static int mode = 1;
    public void fn() {
        BiFunction<Integer, Integer, String> fn = null;
        if(mode == 1) {
            fn = ClassA.myFn(); // This results in an error "Cannot resolve method fn()".
        }
        else {
            //fn = ClassA.myFn2();
        }

        // next I will use fn ...

    }
}
```

This results in an error "Cannot resolve method fn()".

How can I store the function?

Thanks.

Comment: method `fn` is not static, you can't call it on the class

Comment: By `ClassA` in `ClassA.myFn()`, do you mean `A`?

Comment: You may now think about [accepting an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) or comment one to get details ;) to reward those who spent time for you ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `ClassA.myFn()` would require the method to be static **and** this is a method call, you wan't to store the method, not calling it.

1. Lambda

   ```
   BiFunction<Integer, Integer, String> fn = null;
   if(mode == 1) {
       fn = (a, b) -> ClassA.myFn(a, b); 
   }
   ```
2. Method reference

   ```
   BiFunction<Integer, Integer, String> fn = null;
   if(mode == 1) {
       fn = ClassA::myFn; 
   }
   ```

---

⚠️ Also

- both `myFn` and `myFn2` should be static

  ```
  public static String myFn(int a, int b) {
      return "<" + a + " " + b + ">";
  }
  ```
- chosse `ClassA` or `A` but they should be matching

  ```
  class ClassA {
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Your method `myFn` is not static, so you can't access it in a static context like you are trying to do.  Your class is also called `A`, but you reference it as `ClassA`.  Also, when assigning the `BiFunction`, you assign it to the return value, when you want a lambda expression.  Here's an edited copy of your example:

```
class A {
    public static String myFn(int a, int b) { //notice the static keyword
        return "<" + a + " " + b + ">";
    }
    public static String myFn2(int a, int b) { //notice the static keyword
        return "(" + a + " " + b + ")";
    }
}

class B {
    static int mode = 1;
    public void fn() {
        BiFunction<Integer, Integer, String> fn = null;
        if(mode == 1) {
            fn = A::myFn; // use a lambda expression, and class is named A
        }
        else {
            //fn = A::myFn2;
        }

        // next I will use fn ...

    }
}
```